# Porting newlib to a custom ARM setup

Tags: embedded, libc, arm7, newlib

this is my first post, and it covers something which I've been trying to get working on and off for about a year now.

Essentially it boils down to the following: I have a copy of newlib which I'm trying to get working on an LPC2388 (an ARM7TDMI from NXP).  This is on a linux box using arm-elf-gcc

The question I have is that I've been looking at a lot of the tutorials talking about porting newlib, and they all talk about the stubs (like exit, open, read/write, sbrk), and I have a pretty good idea of how to implement all of these functions.  But *where* should I put them?

I have the newlib distribution from sources.redhat.com/pub/newlib/newlib-1.18.0.tar.gz and after poking around I found "syscalls.c" (in newlib-1.18.0/newlib/libc/sys/arm) which contains all of the stubs which I have to update, but they're all filled in with rather finished looking code (which does *NOT* seem to work without the crt0.S, which itself does not work with my chip).

Should I just be wiping out those functions myself, and re-writing them?  Or should I write them somewhere else.  Should I make a whole new folder in newlib/libc/sys with the name of my "architecture" and change the target to match?

I'm also curious if there's proper etiquette on distribution of something like this after releasing it as an open source project.  I currently have a script which downloads binutils, arm-elf-gcc, newlib, and gdb, and compiles them.  If I am modifying files which are in the newlib directory, should I hand a patch which my script auto-applies?  Or should I add the modified newlib to the repository?

Thanks for bothering to read! Following this is a more detailed breakdown of what I'm doing.

---

### For those who want/need more info about my setup:

I'm building a ARM videogame console based loosely on the Uzebox project ( http://belogic.com/uzebox/ ).

I've been doing all sorts of things pulling from a lot of different resources as I try and figure it out.  You can read about the start of my adventures here (sparkfun forums, no one responds as I figure it out on my own): forum.sparkfun.com/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=22072

I followed all of this by reading through the Stackoverflow questions about porting newlib and saw a few of the different tutorials (like wiki.osdev.org/Porting_Newlib ) but they also suffer from telling me to implements stubs without mentioning where, who, what, when, or how!

Comment: Cool project!  This question about software distribution and linking to an existing library is a good fit for Stack Overflow, but you should check out http://electronics.stackexchange.com for answers to questions that deal more with the electronics/firmware side of the project.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I actually know a lot of the firmware/electronics stuff because I work with PIC, msp430, and ATMel microprocessors all the time, but I've never had to do a baremetal arm before, which involves a lot more software development.

As far as these things go I've managed to figure out a lot, but I've been shocked how much material just says "go download the Keil software suite, and then..." which seems like a terrible solution if you're planning on open sourcing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> But where should I put them?

You can put them where you like, so long as they exist in the final link.  You might incorporate them in the libc library itself, or you might keep that generic, and have the syscalls as a separate target specific object file or library.

You may need to create your own target specific crt0.s and assemble and link it for your target.

A good tutorial by Miro Samek of Quantum Leaps on getting GNU/ARM development up and running is available [here](http://www.state-machine.com/arm/Building_bare-metal_ARM_with_GNU.pdf).  The examples are based on an Atmel AT91 part so you will need to know a little about your NXP device to adapt the start-up code.

A ready made Newlib porting layer for LPC2xxx *was* available [here](http://www.aeolusdevelopment.com/Articles/download.html), but the links ot teh files appear to be broken.  The same porting layer is used in Martin Thomas' [WinARM](http://gandalf.arubi.uni-kl.de/avr_projects/arm_projects/#winarm) project.  This is a Windows port of GNU ARM GCC, but the examples included in it are target specific not host specific.

You should only need to modify the porting layer on Newlib, and since it is target *and* application specific, you need not (in fact probably should not) submit your code to the project.

Comment: I actually never planned on submitting it back to redhat, I meant that I was publishing parts of my project as open source with the intent of having other people continue development after I actually built the beginnings of the project.

That tutorial definitely looks cool, I'll be looking through it.

I actually already created a crt0.S and linked it properly (created my own first linker script too!)

I guess another question is that I do "-nostartfiles" and explicitly link my own crt0.o, is there something similar for syscalls (i.e. ignore the built-in newlib syscall.c)?

Comment: If the syscalls symbols are already resolved by an object file or library listed *before* libc (or explicitly linked if libc is implicit - i.e. no -nostdlibs option), the linker will not search for them in the libc library.  So you should not nee to worry about default implementations in the library, your code will override them if your link order correct.

Answer (score 2):

When I was using newlib that is exactly what I did, blew away crt0.s, syscalls.c and libcfunc.c.  My personal preference was to link in the replacement for crt0.s and syscalls.c (rolled the few functions in libcfunc into the syscalls.c replacement) based on the embedded application.

I never had an interest in pushing any of that work back into the distro, so cannot help you there.

You are on the right path though, crt0.S and syscalls.c are where you want to work to customize for your target.  Personally I was interested in a C library (and printf) and would primarily neuter all of the functions to return 0 or 1 or whatever it took to get the function to just work and not get in the way of linking, periodically making the file I/O functions operate on linked in data in rom/ram.  Basically without replacing or modifying any other files in newlib I had a fair amount of success, so you are on the right path.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I actually wasn't planning on pushing it back to the distro, I was planning on releasing my project, and so I was curious where it would be best for the other people who are developing with me.

I'm hoping that eventually, they won't just be people I know so they'll need to be able to find/edit the files themselves!  That was more a question of open source etiquette/project management, which doesn't really have a direct answer.

Thanks for answering though!

Comment: I can think of three choices, pushing back to the project itself, publishing only the changes to newlib with your project wherever it lives, or publishing all of the newlib you used with your changes with  your project.  I think the answer is one of the two latter choices and which depends on how hard it is to build all of newlib plus your project using instructions that you provide, vs providing a complete source package with a complete make system.  That is assuming newlib is gpl like and you can redistrubute with changes.

Comment: I stopped using newlib primarily because of the difficulty I had with building it in/with a cross compiler with the newer gcc versions and eventually just did without newlib all together.  You could start with build instructions for newlib and instructions on how to replace the core files with ones bundled in your release, and depending on the response you get from users adjust that solution.